# bash set -x and stream

Tags: bash

Can you explain the output of the following test script to me:

```
# prepare test data
echo "any content" > myfile

# set bash to inform me about the commands used
set -x

cat < myfile
```

output:

```
+cat
any content
```

Namely why does the line starting with + not show the "< myfile" bit?

How to force bash to do that. I need to inform the user of my script's doings as in:

```
mysql -uroot < the_new_file_with_a_telling_name.sql
```

and I can't.

**EDIT**: additional context: I use variables. Original code:

```
SQL_FILE=`ls -t $BACKUP_DIR/default_db* | head -n 1` # get latest db
mysql -uroot mydatabase < ${SQL_FILE}
```

`-v` won't expand variables and `cat file.sql | mysql` will produce two lines:

```
+mysql
+cat file.sql
```

so neither does the trick.

Comment: Basically, that's the way `bash` works with its `-x` command.  There isn't a trivial way around it in general.  In this specific case, you can use `cat myfile` to achieve the same result and you'll see `myfile` in the output.

Comment: cat was probably a wrong example, the origin was the mysql command

Comment: Fair enough; that's an occupational hazard on SO, addressing extra-simplified scripts. It's also why I distinguished this specific case from the general case; `mysql` is an example of the general case. However, many commands will read a file named on the command line; won't `mysql` do that? Also, at the risk of castigation for (almost) UUOC, you could use `cat myfile | mysql ...` so that the name of the file is visible in the trace output. There's a specific reason for an otherwise useless use of `cat` here, namely to make the file name visible under trace. With a brief comment, that's OK.

Comment: didn't know about UUOC, seems like I'm fit for it. I edited the question, seems like that UUOC entry won't work either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `set -v` or `set -o verbose` instead which enables command echoing.

Example run on my machine:

```
[me@home]$ cat x.sh 
echo "any content" > myfile
set -v
cat < myfile

[me@home]$ bash x.sh 
cat < myfile
any content
```

The caveat here is that `set -v` simply echos the command literally and does not do any shell expansion or iterpolation. As pointed out by Jonathan in the comments, this can be a problem if the filename is defined in a variable (e.g. `command < $somefile`) making it difficult to identify what `$somefile` refers to.

Comment: Good idea...it shows the source though, so if the code were: `file=Myfile; echo Hi > $file; cat < $file` and the script were big enough, it might be hard to spot the value of `$file`.  You could use `sh -xv` (or `set -x -v`) to get both lots of output.

Answer (score 3):

The difference there is quite simple:

- in the first case, you're using the program `cat`, and you're redirecting the contents of `myfile` to the standard input of `cat`. This means you're executing `cat`, and that's what `bash` shows you when you have `set -x`;
- in a possible second case, you could use `cat myfile`, as pointed by @Jonathan Leffler, and you'd see `+cat myfile`, which is what you're executing: the program `cat` with the parameter `myfile`.

From `man bash`:

```
  -x      After  expanding  each  simple  command,  for command, case command,
          select command, or arithmetic  for  command,  display  the  expanded
          value  of PS4, followed by the command and its expanded arguments or
          associated word list.
```

As you can see, it simply displays the command line expanded, and its argument list -- redirections are neither part of the expanded command `cat` nor part of its argument list.

As pointed by @Shawn Chin, you may use `set -v`, which, as from `man bash`:

```
  -v      Print shell input lines as they are read.
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, that's the way `bash` works with its `-x` command.  I checked on a Solaris 5.10 box, and the `/bin/sh` there (which is close to a genuine Bourne shell) also omits I/O redirection.

Given the command file (`x3.sh`):

```
echo "Hi" > Myfile
cat < Myfile
rm -f Myfile
```

The trace output on the Solaris machine was:

```
$ sh -x x3.sh
+ echo Hi 
+ cat 
Hi
+ rm -f Myfile 
$ /bin/ksh -x x3.sh
+ echo Hi
+ 1> Myfile
+ cat
+ 0< Myfile
Hi
+ rm -f Myfile
$ bash -x x3.sh
+ echo Hi
+ cat
Hi
+ rm -f Myfile
$
```

Note that `bash` and `sh` (which are definitely different executables) produce the same output.  The `ksh` output includes the I/O redirection information — score 1 for the Korn shell.

In this specific example, you can use:

```
cat myfile
```

to see the name of the file.  In the general case, it is hard, but consider using `ksh` instead of `bash` to get the I/O redirection reported.